# Characterize convex sets that are the convex hull of their extreme points

Tags: convex-analysis, convex-hulls

The famous Krein-Milman theorem states that every compact convex set in a topological vector space is the convex hull of its extreme points. Note, however, that many convex sets exist in $\mathbb R^n$ which are not bounded but still the convex hull of their extreme points (e.g. the closed epigraph of a parabola), so I was wondering whether a true characterization (not a sufficient condition) for this property exists in finite-dimensional spaces: which closed convex sets are the convex hulls of their extreme points? All my search results lead to the Krein-Milman theorem which doesn't interest me. Due to the huge literature on convex sets I can't imagine that this hasn't been attempted before.

Comment: In the Banach space setting, there is the Krein-Milman property (closed bounded convex sets have extreme points). If the space is a dual space, KMP is equivalent to the so- called Radon-Nikodym property. There is a  good deal of literature on RNP.

Comment: Choquet, later Alfsen investigated convex cones (unbounded sets) and extreme rays. Maybe you also would like to take a look at https://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/0022247X74902340?via%3Dihub